# Watch Me - What are We?

Tags: riddle

> We think you can see us everyday.
>
> You don't even have to look closely.
>
> You cannot smell us, nor can you feel, hear or taste us.
>
> But we are somehow essential!
>
> Because in the end, it comes down to us...
>
> ... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.
>
> But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.
>
> And when we come together, beautiful can arise.
>
> Nevertheless, for some people... we and our childs are a hex.
>
> But we hope that we can help those this way.

A big hint:

> "We" are three

Comment: made it a bit easier!

Comment: edited the riddle and added a hint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of two answers in one, not sure which one fits better.

Are you:

> Red Green Blue, the primary colors.
> Alternatively, you can interpret Red Green Blue as the three charges of the strong nuclear force.

We think you can see us everyday.

You don't even have to look closely.

> You see colors around you everyday.
> Alternatively, everything we see around us is made of particles held together by the strong nuclear force, though you would have to look very closely indeed to see particles that contain the individual charges themselves.

You cannot smell us, nor can you feel, hear or taste us.

> Color cannot be smelt, felt, heard, or tasted, only seen.
> Or, the strong nuclear force acts at such a small scale that humans cannot normally interact with it.

But we are somehow essential!

Because in the end, it comes down to us...

> In the end, everything we see is composed of a combination of these colors.
> Or, many of the particles that we normally interact with are composed of elementary particles with one of these charges.

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> Not sure about this, without color we can't see anything but I guess objects can still exist.
> Or, many of there particles we interact with everyday would not exist without the strong nuclear charges.

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.

> Most things contain a multitude of colors and at least two of the primary colors must be combined to create most of the colors we see.
> Or, fermions(of which protons and neutrons are a part of) must have neutral charge so at least two charges(a color and an anti-color) must combine to create one, though most of the particles around us(portions and neutrons) are a combination of three charges.

And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

> When the primary colors combine they can create many beautiful images.
> The strong charges coming together are partially responsible for all the beauty in the universe.

Nevertheless, for some people... we and our childs are a hex.

> In software development colors are often represented in hexadecimal.
> Hex can also mean 6, if you count the anti-colors you can say there are actually 6 color charges.

But we hope that we can help those this way.

Comment: Correct answer! I knew I should give a big hint... :D 
"... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist." - please reason this sentence. Don't think in objects. The answer of "we are somehow essential" is nearly the same.

Comment: The right answer is RGB (Red, Green and Blue) :-)

Answer (score 8):

Is the answer

> Oxygen?

We think you can see us every day.
You don't even have to look closely.

> Oxygen surrounds us and we don't have to look for it

In the end, it comes down to us...
... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> essential for living

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.
And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

> people breathe O2 and O3 protects us from harmful sun rays

Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.
But we hope that we can help you that way.

> Oxygen has 6 valence electrons and can be considered a "hex"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please feel free to take the Tour. Very creative and logicak answr, nice job! +1.

Comment: This is a really nice answer! The thing that bother me. Is the "we think you can us evryday". This answer dont fit well To me.

Comment: Good answer! Though it's not the answer. 
The part "We think you can see us everyday" doesn't fit that well, but nevertheless a good guess!

Answer (score 1):

New Answer:
I think it is

> Water. Again, water is existent in almost everywhere (though harder to find in areas like the sahara - unless your sweating). Water is *essential* for life to exist. In addition, two hydrogen atoms must combine to make a water molecule, and when combined, it can form life. However, for some living species water can be a curse (or feared) or mixed with substances cab make poison. Two water molecules alsi result in six total elements). But in the end water is essential to living.

---

Old Answer (Disproved by OP)

It is

> Life. You can see evidence of life everywhere, and without life - well you don't exist. In order to have more life there has to be two living same species (except asexual reproduction). When we come together, etc. self explanatory. For some people life is a curse, or they don't like their life, but by living, life is helping you.

Comment: the best guess since now! It fits every criteria - nevertheless, it's not the right answer! Keep Guessing ;)

Comment: a good second guess - but not the right one. Tipp: The first two sentences in my riddle are obvious. So think really simple.

Answer (score 1):

It could be

> Glasses!

```
We think you can see us everyday.

You don't even have to look closely.
```

> I can see them everyday without looking closely. In fact I'm seeing right through them.

```
In the end, it comes down to us...

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.
```

> At least personally, my vision's so bad I can't function/exist without em.

```
But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.
```

> You need two lenses to form a pair of glasses.

```
And when we come together, beautiful can arise.
```

> When I wear my glasses I can create art. I can cook. I can read. I can do nice things.

```
Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.

But we hope that we can help you that way.
```

> I hate the fact that I'm cursed with terrible vision. But glad I can use them.

Though arguably given the logic in my answer, many objects that

> exist in pairs. Like a nice pair of longjohns hidden under my pants in this cold Canadian winter

can apply as solutions to this riddle?

Comment: Thanks for your answer - unfortunately it is wrong.
Actually, we (in the riddle) are not two (so we are not a pair).

Answer (score 1):

> Oxygen

We think you can see us everyday.

You don't even have to look closely.

> Oxygen makes up the air around us.

In the end, it comes down to us...

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> Essential for life.

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.

> Oxygen is diatomic - meaning that it naturally forms molecules of two (O2)

And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.

But we hope that we can help you that way.

> Oxygen has 6 valence electrons - hex(credit to YeetKid)

Comment: Welcome to Ouzzling SE! Just in case you were unaware, @YeetKid already guessed the same answer as yours earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> Microorganisms

We think you can see us everyday.

You don't even have to look closely.

> You can easily see microorganism colonies (bread mold etc)

In the end, it comes down to us...

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> Gut bacteria, mitochondria

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.

And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

> Colonies, mushrooms, multi-celled organisms, mitochondria etc

Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.

But we hope that we can help those way.

> Viruses/bacteria/mold can harm people with illnesses but also cure/aide others

Comment: Good guess - but not the right one :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> The sun, moon, and stars?

We think you can see us everyday.

> You can see the sun and the moon everyday and usually stars.

You don't even have to look closely.

> You do not need a telescope to see the sun, moon, and most stars.

You cannot smell us, nor can you feel, hear or taste us.

> The moon is not made out of cheese...sooo...and we certainly can't touch fire.

But we are somehow essential!

> The sun gives us warmth, the moon gives us tides, and the stars are pretty.

Because in the end, it comes down to us...

> No sun = no heat = no earth

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> Same as above.

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.

> Sun and the moon form a team.

And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

> The sunrise and sunset = beautiful.

Nevertheless, for some people... we and our childs are a hex.

> Some people think so.

But we hope that we can help those this way.

> I don't know about this part.

It could either be that, or:

> The three main elements: fire, air, and water

Comment: Actually there are four elements: you forgot earth/rock/ground

Comment: Oops! -face palm-

Comment: Besides that though, I like your answer

Comment: I already +1(ed) you

Answer (score 0):

Are you..

> Oxygen?

```
We think you can see us everyday.
```

> We do, mostly just as air.

```
You don't even have to look closely.
```

> Oxygen doesn't need to be looked for closely, since it is everywhere.

```
In the end, it comes down to us...
```

> Because without them we can't breath.

```
... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.
```

> Most animals wouldn't exist.

```
But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.
```

> Oxygen 2 makes up of 20% of our atmosphere, a team!

```
And when we come together, beautiful can arise.
```

> Life!

```
Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.
```

> People want to deoxygenate. And rust, we hate rust.

```
But we hope that we can help you that way.
```

> Its a natural process that oxygen does so, helping in that way keeps the balance.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Just as a heads-up, this answer has already been suggested twice, though your reasoning is slightly different. In future, please check the existing answers before posting an answer, in case your answer has already been given.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> light (or monochromotic light)

We think you can see us everyday.

> we can see sunlight everyday

You don't even have to look closely.

> no need to look closely as light comes itself to your eyes.

In the end, it comes down to us...

> all you see is thanks to light, so we can say that in someway.

... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.

> Without light, most of the species won't exist (maybe some submarines species could have emerged though)

But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.

> There I don't have a good explanation, could be that a monochromatic isn't enough for most species and we need at least two.

And when we come together, beautiful can arise.

> Together and with the help of water, monochromatic lights can make a rainbow which beautiful.

Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.

> for lunar child, sun is an hex!

But we hope that we can help you that way.

> No idea there

Answer (score 0):

Are you...

> **Carbon**

My reasoning is as follows:

*We think you can see us everyday.
You don't even have to look closely.*

> Carbon exists in many visible forms like coal, diamonds, etc.

*In the end, it comes down to us...
... because without us, so many wouldn't even exist.*

> Carbon underpins all life forms like animals, plants, etc.

*But to let so many exist, at least two of us have to form a team.
And when we come together, beautiful can arise.*

> Carbon forms complex bonds and chains (e.g. hydrocarbons, sugars) to create things, and these links often have beauty due to symmetry

*Nevertheless, for some people... we are a hex.
But we hope that we can help you that way.*

> Carbon often creates rings of 6 carbon atoms (e.g. [benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene))

Answer (score 0):

is it

> gears in a watch?

is it that obvious or am I just that dumb?

> people often look at clocks and don't recognize the function of the gears below that also require 2 or more gears working together to function. and time is a hex...anyway. gears or time I suppose

Comment: Good guess, but no ;-)